# Laravel For Loop is deleting 'level' key

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop

I am facing a peculiar problem.
I have this array:

```
    array:2 [▼
    0 => array:7 [▼
    "factor_color" => "#000066"
    "score" => 2.5
    "level" => 3
    "title" => "Impression Management"
    "description" => """
  <p>\r\n
  \tImpression management is the tendency to project an unrealistically positive image while answering to the questions. This tendency is being captured by use of an intelligence algorithm which monitors candidate`s response pattern on the questions and calculates if the candidate is trying to project highly positive image about himself/herself.</p>\r\n
  """

    "interpretation" => ""
    "rescale_type" => "none"
  ]
  1 => array:7 [▼
    "factor_color" => "#ff0000"
    "score" => 0.588235
    "level" => 1
    "title" => "Mid Response Tendency"
   "description" => """
  <p>\r\n
  \tThe tendency to answer middle points of the scales or &#39;cannot say&#39; answer option more than most candidates. This indicates the level of test-inhibition the candidate had while answering to the questions on this test. A high score generally indicates that the candidate was apprehensive about the test so he/she took the middle path and prefered to stay safe rather than displaying his/her true preference.</p>\r\n
  """
   "interpretation" => ""
   "rescale_type" => "none"
  ]
]
```

I am passing this array to for loop in a file I created to store custom functions for my app.
$count = count($factor_data);

```
    for ($i=0;$i<=$count-1;$i++) {

        $title = trim($factor_data[$i]['title']);
        $color = $factor_data[$i]['factor_color'];
        $description = $factor_data[$i]['description']? trim($factor_data[$i]['description']):false;
        $interpretation = ($factor_data[$i]['interpretation'])?trim($factor_data[$i]['interpretation']):false;
        $score = $factor_data[$i]['level']?:round($factor_data[$i]['score']);//line 517

        print_r($factor_data[$i]); continue;
```

Here is the result for print_r():

```
    Array ( [factor_color] => #000066 
    [score] => 2.5 
    [level] => 3 
    [title] =>    Impression Management 
    [description] =>
    [interpretation] => 
    [rescale_type] => none 
    ) 

   Array ( 
    [factor_color] => #ff0000 
    [score] => 0.588235 
    [level] => 1 
    [title] => Mid Response Tendency 
    [description] =>
    [interpretation] => 
    [rescale_type] => none 
    )
```

but Laravel5.2 gives this error:

```
ErrorException in ReportPDF.php line 517:
Undefined index: level
```

What am I doing wrong? If I just delete $score variable or replace it by a constant value it works fine.

Comment: I have omitted the 'description' text from print_r(). here is the actual print_r() result:
Array ( [factor_color] => #000066 [score] => 2.5 [level] => 3 [title] => Impression Management [description] =>
Impression management is the tendency to project an unrealistically positive image while answering to the questions. This tendency is being captured by use of an intelligence algorithm which monitors candidate`s response pattern on the questions and calculates if the candidate is trying to project highly positive image about himself/herself.
[interpretation] => [rescale_type] => none )

Comment: Array ( [factor_color] => #ff0000 [score] => 0.588235 [level] => 1 [title] => Mid Response Tendency [description] =>
The tendency to answer middle points of the scales or 'cannot say' answer option more than most candidates. This indicates the level of test-inhibition the candidate had while answering to the questions on this test. A high score generally indicates that the candidate was apprehensive about the test so he/she took the middle path and prefered to stay safe rather than displaying his/her true preference.
[interpretation] => [rescale_type] => none )

Comment: Maybe you need to add a default value for correct `$score = $factor_data[$i]['level']?0:round($factor_data[$i]['score']);`

Comment: This code is fine. Problem must be somewhere else. What happens before loop?

Comment: Thank you D.Cichowski, the problem was in the loop which is calling this loop. I found it out. All is working well now. Thank you.

Comment: `for ($i=0;$i<=$count-1;$i++)`
Shouldn't it be `for ($i=0;$i<$count-1;$i++)` (I replaced <= by <)